# Getting the exact author and articles with JOIN Clause in mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Any help will be highly appreciated!

I am trying to get information about SINGLE author (for example the first author with first ID from the table) and to display all of his articles, and nothing more than that.

I am trying the following code, using LEFT-JOIN clause, and getting the first author with all of his articles, BUT ALSO and other authors and articles.

I am new into this clauses, and some help will be so useful.

Should I change the clause or ?

```
$sql = <<<TAG
    SELECT authors.name as author_name,
           articles.title as article_title,
           articles.text as article_text,
           articles.author_id
    FROM authors
    LEFT JOIN articles
    ON authors.id = articles.author_id
TAG;


$result = mysqli_query($foo_connection, $sql);


if($result) {


    foreach($result as $key => $item_data){

        print $item_data['author_name']. " - " . $item_data['article_title'] . " - " . $item_data['article_text'] ."<br>";

    }

}
else {
    print "Something went wrong! ".mysqli_errno($sql);
}
```

Comment: You may have to mention a where clause to filter the author and the articles

Comment: What do you mean by WHERE clause?

Comment: (INNER) JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both tables
LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table
RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table
FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records when there is a match in either left or right table

These are the clauses we are learning now :(

Comment: Left Join will return all data from left table.If you want to fetch only single data add that condition in where clause.like `Where authors.id = 1` or required id or such condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter your results with the author ID.
If you want to dynamically select the author ID then you'll have to do two requests - first one where you select the first author (with LIMIT 1) and second one where you select all articles for this author.

You can also do a subquery in your where clause, by example:

```
SELECT authors.name as author_name,
       articles.title as article_title,
       articles.text as article_text,
       articles.author_id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN articles
ON authors.id = articles.author_id
WHERE authors.id IN (SELECT id FROM authors LIMIT 1)
```

This request will select only the first author of the table (as no where clause defined and no order, basically first statement).

EDIT:

If you already have the author ID from somewhere else:

```
SELECT authors.name as author_name,
       articles.title as article_title,
       articles.text as article_text,
       articles.author_id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN articles
ON authors.id = articles.author_id
WHERE authors.id = xxx
```

Replace **xxx** with your author ID.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_errno() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECTS\Php-joins\Php-left-right-join\index.php on line 34
Something went wrong!

Comment: Line 34 is the mysql_errno in the if ($result).. Which means something in the code above is not correct?

Comment: I get it, just changed the XXX with the authors ID , didn't notice that! :) Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - regarding your error, the parameter you pass to mysql_errno isn't correct- you pass the request string instead of the mysqli link. You should pass $foo_connection instead.